# SOAP Response error -must not contain the < character

Tags: soap, wsdl

Getting error as

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in preInvoke : javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 47; The value of attribute "arasAML" associated with an element type "tcin:applyAMLInTCInputData" must not contain the '&lt;' character.
```

I am testing my Webservice in `SOAP` UI , below is the `SOAP` request.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; xmlns:tcin="de4.com/Schemas/TCIntgn/2013-05/TCIntegration">; <soapenv:Header/> <soapenv:Body> <tcin:ApplyAMLInTCInput> <tcin:applyAMLInTCInputData arasAML="<XML><REVISIONS><ITEM_REVISION><itemNo>000147</itemNo><type>PDF,DirectM‌​odel,MSPowerPointX</type></ITEM_REVISION></REVISIONS></XML>" message="DownloadDatasetFile" > </tcin:applyAMLInTCInputData> </tcin:ApplyAMLInTCInput> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

getting `SOAP` response as below

```
     <faultstring>java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in preInvoke : javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 47; The value of attribute "arasAML" associated with an element type "tcin:applyAMLInTCInputData" must not contain the '&lt;' character.</faultstring>
```

Comment: SOAP Request <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tcin="http://de4.com/Schemas/TCIntgn/2013-05/TCIntegration">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tcin:ApplyAMLInTCInput>
         <tcin:applyAMLInTCInputData arasAML="<XML><REVISIONS><ITEM_REVISION><itemNo>000147</itemNo><type>PDF,DirectModel,MSPowerPointX</type></ITEM_REVISION></REVISIONS></XML>" message="DownloadDatasetFile" >
         </tcin:applyAMLInTCInputData>
      </tcin:ApplyAMLInTCInput>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode your data or put it into a CDATA block if it's going to contain special characters like < and >.